# How to dynamically change GlyphIndices in tag GlyphRun?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I'd like to show some text dynamically in XAML (GlyphRunDrawing) by binding GlyphIndices to some  string in my C# code, but it does not work well.

The code below works well:

```
GlyphRunDrawing ForegroundBrush="Black">
            <GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
                <GlyphRun 
                    GlyphIndices="33 66" 
                    BaselineOrigin="3,25"  
                    FontRenderingEmSize="15" 
                    AdvanceWidths="9 0" 
                    >
                    <GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                        <GlyphTypeface FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TAHOMA.TTF" />
                    </GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                </GlyphRun>
            </GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
        </GlyphRunDrawing
```

when I modified the "GlyphIndices="33 66"" to 
"GlyphIndices="{Binding  Source={StaticResource MyStringData}, Path=title}"/>", it does't.

Can anybody tell why and how I should do?